# Mysql default value from wordpress form query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to work out a mysql query from a wordpress form submission.

**Currently my query is:**

```
INSERT INTO blah (`blah`, `blah`, `blah`, `blah`, `blah`, `blah`, `blah`, `blah`, `blah`) VALUES ("{11}", "{2}", "{6}", "{5}", "{4}", "{16}", "{7}", "{15}", "{10}")
```

If one of the values from the form (*an image file location*) is left empty I'd like it to be replaced with a default value (*image file location*)

Thanks for any help!

Alex

Comment: use it with if ...else  condition in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can check data before send the query and give them a default value like this:

```
if($img == '') $img = "your/path/to/image.jpg";
```